# Jenkins SMTP Configuration - 535 Authentication Failed

Tags: email, jenkins, jenkins-groovy

I'm trying to configure Jenkins email notification via Mailer plugin 1.21.

I'm using secureserver.net as a mailing server.

I have a problem with "SMTP Authentication", the "Test configuration" is reporting 535 Authentication:

> Failed to send out e-mail
>
> javax.mail.AuthenticationFailedException: 535 Authentication Failed
>   for jenkins@xxxx.com
>
> at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport$Authenticator.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:809)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.authenticate(SMTPTransport.java:752)
>     at
>   com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:669)
>     at javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:317)     at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)  at
>   javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:125)  at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:194)    at
>   javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:124)

My settings are as follows:

```
SMTP server: smtpout.secureserver.net

Use SMTP Authentication: yes
User Name: jenkins@xxxx.com
Password: ******

Use SSL - yes
SMTP Port - 465
Charset - UTF-8
```

I'm using the same credentials to connect via webmail: https://email11.secureserver.net/webmail.php. I don't have a connection problem.

Do you have any explanation why jenkins refuse to authenticate?

Comment: any help? Please

Answer (score 1):

As google doesn't allow login from less secure apps you have do the following steps:
1. Login to "https://myaccount.google.com/security"
2. Enable "Allow less secure apps" to "ON"

Then check the "Test configuration" in jenkins.

Comment: I'm not using a google account to send email notification

Answer (score 1):

From https://products.secureserver.net/email/email_outlook.htm:

> NOTE: "smtpout.secureserver.net" is an SMTP relay server. In order to
>   use this server to send e-mails, you must first activate SMTP relay on
>   your e-mail account. Log on to your Manage Email Accounts page to set
>   up SMTP relay.

Did you do this?

Comment: Yes I did it, and it works now, thank you. Also, I had an error due to copy/paste operation of the email address. So I used the wrong address to send an email ! Sorry for that

Answer (score 0):

I solved similar issue by creating a **new SMTP credential** from AWS SES.
But I am still amazed why old credentials didn't work with jenkins even if it was working with other applications.